# Multiply decimal number for price

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP, and for a woocommerce I'm trying to multiply a price by 2.

```
$priceOriginal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); // return 450,00€
$priceNoCur  = preg_replace( '/&.*?;/', '', $priceOriginal );  // return 450,00
$priceNoCurDot = preg_replace( '/,/', '.', $priceNoCur);  // return 450.00
$priceFinalDot = floatval($priceNoCurDot) * 2;
echo $priceFinalDot;   // return 0
```

I found how to delete de euro sign and change the coma by a dot, but when I multiply by two my result is 0 … why !?

**SOLUTION**

I find a other way to call the price : `$priceOriginal = WC()->cart->total;` then I was able to multiply this number as a normal calculation.

Comment: I can't duplicate it. Double-check your variables along the way.

Comment: You don't need to `preg_replace` anything if you're using `floatval`. https://3v4l.org/KIMmE

Comment: Isn't it `floatval` instead who is returning 0?

Comment: It looks like WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); return string(119) "450,00€", so I think this is the problem right ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `priceOriginal` is not what telling, if I assume it is some thing like "450,00€" then I must return `900` when you multiple it by `2`. try to `var_dump($priceOriginal);` before doing any further operation

```
$priceOriginal = "450,00€";
$priceNoCur  = preg_replace( '/&.*?;/', '', $priceOriginal );  // return 450,00
$priceNoCurDot = preg_replace( '/,/', '.', $priceNoCur);  // return 450.00
$priceFinalDot = floatval($priceNoCurDot) * 2;
echo $priceFinalDot;   // returns 900
```

For debug:

```
$priceOriginal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
var_dump($priceOriginal); //see what you get
```

**As per your comment**, If it is returning `string(119) "450,00€"`,then you should trim your `$priceOriginal` variable like `$priceOriginal = trim(WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal());` before doing further operation because It may have some extra space characters.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. It returns string(119) "450,00€" …

Comment: but if it is only `450,00€` then it should return `string(9) "450,00€" ` not string(**119**), I think you need `trim()` if you've other spaces with your money string..

Comment: @Alex See my edit and let me know whether it is working or no?

Comment: So I do $priceOriginal = trim(WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()); var_dump($priceOriginal); and still return string(119) "450,00€"

Comment: Then your $priceOriginal contains non-printable characters. Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102962/why-would-var-dump-return-a-bigger-value-than-the-string-length?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I finally found a other way to call the price : $priceOriginal = WC()->cart->total; then I was able to multiply this number as a normal calculation. Thanks for your help