# PHP - DateTime::createFromFormat() returns null

Tags: php

I have this code...

```php
class log{
    private $dateTime;
    private $message;

    function log($dt, $message){
        $this->dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', substr($dt, 0, -1)); 
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    function get_dateTime(){
        return $this->dateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    }
    function get_message(){
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

In parameter `$dt` has format `17/05/2019 03:15:42:`. I get it by reading a text file.

I read the file and create the class object:

```php
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false && $line !="\n") { //format example : 30/04/2019 07:59:14: File creation.
   $date = strtok($line, " ");
   $hour = strtok(" ");
   $message = strtok("");

   $log = new log($date." ".$hour,$message);
   echo $log->get_dateTime()."<br>";
}
```

The result is: **Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in...**

If I pass the parameter "manually" it works fine.

```php
$log2 = new log('30/04/2019 07:59:14:',"test");
echo $log2->get_dateTime()."<br>";
```

If I use code
`echo $date;` Correct date is returned. Same if I make `echo $hour;`

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure that `$dt` has a trailing colon? `var_dump($dt);` and `var_dump($this->dateTime);` in your log function to see what each contains.

Comment: Note, constructors named to match your class have been deprecated since 2015, they should be named `__construct()` instead.

Comment: Because format readed from file is ```30/04/2019 07:59:14:``` So I remove ```:```.

Comment: Same result if I use ```__construct()```. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($date, $hour);` and post the results. We need to see what the variables actually contains (since we can't debug your code ourselves).

Comment: ```echo var_dump($date,$hour);``` returns ```string(13) "30/04/2019" string(9) "07:59:14:"``` I do not understand it. Date should be string(10), right?

Comment: There must be some row in the file you're iterating through that has a different format. Tested your code (changed the constructor to `__construct()` instead of `log()` since that throws a deprecation warning) and it seem to work just fine: [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/dl2G2)

Comment: Maybe any special char like ```/r``` or similar makes string larger?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102962/why-would-var-dump-return-a-bigger-value-than-the-string-length) it seems to be because file encoding. ```string(23) "30/04/2019 07:59:14:" ->ef bb bf 33 30 2f 30 34 2f 32 30 31 39 20 30 37 3a 35 39 3a 31 34 3a
string(20) "30/04/2019 07:59:14:" ->33 30 2f 30 34 2f 32 30 31 39 20 30 37 3a 35 39 3a 31 34 3a```

Answer (score 0):

Problems seems to be the file encoing. When checking line section in hexadecimal it seems to use 3 byte more than when passing text manually.

file seccion in HEX: `ef bb bf 33 30 2f 30 34 2f 32 30 31 39 20 30 37 3a 35 39 3a 31 34 3a`

same text in HEX passed manually: `33 30 2f 30 34 2f 32 30 31 39 20 30 37 3a 35 39 3a 31 34 3a`

Also string size is different (string(23) and string(20)) checking it with `var_dump` function.

File is in UTF8 encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8